# Why was my question so quickly deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, deleted-questions

I [asked a question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/337699/first-php-framework-before-studying-symfony) and it was deleted WITHOUT any polite explanation, by [Thomas Owens](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/4/thomas-owens):

> I want to learn Symfony but I think, learning Symfony as a first framework is a TITANIC task for someone who knows nothing about web frameworks.
>
> So, I want to learn a simple framework to make a smooth transition to Symfony.
>
> What is the best framework to study with the aim to jump to Symfony?
>
> Silex? CodeIgniter? Other?
>
> Any suggestions are welcome.

In Stack Overflow my question is not considered a good one, but I understand the reasons.

In programmers.stackexchange.com (now renamed), I don't understand what was my FAULT.

Can you please explain me how can I get an answer for my question, let me HAVE TIME to read the answer and then delete my question if you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My book-recommendation question on very specific topic was deleted](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8305/my-book-recommendation-question-on-very-specific-topic-was-deleted)

Comment: see also: [Why was my question closed or down voted?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487)

Comment: @amon you are right, but if this site has a «be nice policy», I think that by imediatly delete other peoples questions doesn't fit in those «be nice policies». If I'm in a Math forum and someone ask me: «Why 2+2=4?» I'll try to approach the level of thinking of that person. There are no such thing of "stupid question" and all question deserves an answer.

Comment: @user256083 Being nice doesn't have anything to do with removing off-topic questions, nor with the speed of their removal.  You're right, there are no stupid questions, but if you ask really basic questions more than once, you're probably better off doing some fundamental research yourself first.  There's no such thing as "all questions deserve answers;" you wouldn't consider a question that essentially attacks someone else's position for no good reason worthy of an answer or even your attention.

Comment: @RobertHarveyn **«there are no stupid questions, but if you ask really basic questions more than once»**. It was my first (and last, I hope) question.

Comment: "*Can you please explain me how can I get an answer for my question, let me HAVE TIME to read the answer and then delete my question if you want?*" No, we won't be doing that. That would be an *abuse* of the system. If your question is appropriate for the site, then there's no reason for it to be deleted. If your question is inappropriate for the site, then there is no reason for it to be *answered*. As such, there shouldn't be an answer for you to read; if one happens to slip through, there's no damage done from making it inaccessible to you.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it looks like OP is not fully honest in what they say about all questions being good and deserving answers. If they really believed in what they say, they would hold their views everywhere. But, you see, they don't: "In Stack Overflow my question is not considered a good one..." and they even pretend to understand the reasons. Maybe they are like those [lost souls from Math.SE](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7826/31260) who believe in funny fairy tales about "undergraduate level stack exchange"

Answer (score 12):

If you read [the Help Center's page about what you can ask about here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) prior to posting, you would see that some questions aren't a good fit for this environment, specifically questions about "finding or recommending products or services, including tools, libraries or packages, programming languages, books, scholarly papers, tutorials, articles, or blogs" or "career or education advice". Both are linked to more detailed Meta posts about why [finding/recommendation](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487) or [career/education](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/are-career-advice-questions-useful-to-anyone-except-the-poster) advice questions don't fit here.

We also have advice from Shog9, one of the Stack Exchange Community Managers that [it is perfectly acceptable to delete everything that is blatantly off-topic on-sight](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21?m=31225279#31225279). Because your question fell into one of the topics that was specifically deemed by our community to be off-topic and documented as such in the Help Center, I deleted it.

We have no obligation to keep your question around if it doesn't meet our community's standards. That's how it works here. Next time, you should read a site's rules and standards before posting your question.