# Are diagramming skills off topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

[How to draw nice looking pointy oriented hexagon shape in monospace plaintext](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/351088/131624)

I've read plenty of specs over the years. Some by people I wish had taken the time to ask a simple question like this. Do we really want the next generation to be completely dependent on tools like Microsoft Visio?

Comment: FWIW, I liked your answer to the original question :)

Answer (score 5):

Questions about diagrams IMHO can be on-topic if the specific focus of the question is how to use diagrams for things like

- a software concept, or
- documenting software or software architecture
- documenting requirements

For example, a question like *how can I draw round corners* is not specific for software development, a question like *is there a consensus to use round corners for the "Foo" elements in the UML diagram type "Bar" to express semantics XYZ* could be on-topic.

In my point of view, the question in stake is more of the former type than of the latter (but YMMV), so I think it should stay closed.

Since the OP mentioned it in his "[answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8567/9113)" here: a question like *"I try to design a domain specific language for unit testing using ASCII art, but I have trouble with the semantics (or unambiguity) for this and that reason"* could have been on-topic. Just asking how to improve the look for ASCII art, however, not.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see how this relates to our scope of "professionals, academics, and students working within the systems development life cycle". Yes, we create diagrams , but creating shapes in plain text formats is not unique to software development. You could argue that this is about how to use a text editor to create a diagram rather than the process of creating or maintaining a diagram. You could also argue that it's more about art or design than the diagram. I don't see how you could argue that this is about methods and practices, requirements, architecture, design, quality assurance, testing, configuration management, build, release, or deployment.

Can you make a case as to why this question fits into our scope?

Answer (score 2):

Programmers simply do the most ascii art by far. And in fact, I will use the answer for writing a new unit test domain specific language.

What would be a suitable SE place to ask this question?

Comment: see [I have a question, but it may not fit best on Software Engineering. Where else can I ask it?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8066/31260)

Comment: Obviously I know multiple SE sites exist. I'm asking what the right one would be for linked question.

Comment: There may be no suitable SE community to ask this (or any) question. None are jumping out. Even if a question is good, there may be no community that decides that it is on-topic for them.

Comment: So the flaw in the system is that offtopics should be moved, not closed. And if no suitable alternative exist, it IMHO should not be moved.Current policy is a bit deletionist-y.

Comment: "We have no obligation to keep your question around if it doesn't meet our community's standards. That's how it works here. Next time, you should read a site's rules and standards before posting your question." ([Why was my question so quickly deleted by a moderator?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8351/31260))