# Why was my question deleted which was closed within the past 48 hours

Tags: support, bug

I'm reading [Why and how are some questions deleted](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions).

> Questions that have been closed within the past 48 hours cannot be
> deleted, so as to allow for editing and possible reopening.

My [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/420336/55978) was deleted nonetheless.

> This post is hidden. It was deleted 10 hours ago by gnat, Jörg W
> Mittag, Doc Brown.

> Add details and clarify the problem you’re solving. This will help
> others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new
> one.
>
> Closed 16 hours ago.

[image]

There is a good answer now and I want to accept the answer.

What can I do to improve the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why was my question so quickly deleted by a moderator?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8350/why-was-my-question-so-quickly-deleted-by-a-moderator) "We have no obligation to keep your question around if it doesn't meet our community's standards. That's how it works here. Next time, you should read a site's rules and standards before posting your question."

Comment: help center page you linked to refers more detailed FAQ, have you read it? "The community-curated FAQ contains more details about deleted posts." As for what you can do to improve, as an author you can edit this question and flag for moderator attention requesting to undelete. Bringing to meta how you did here is also a valid option, in this case question can also be edited and voted undelete by users having 10K+ reputation

Comment: I haven't read the FAQ previously.  I read it now.

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason is that some users have the privilege to vote to close questions  under certain conditions

> ... can vote to delete closed questions within 48 hours of being closed,
> so long as they score −3 or lower.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/314511

Would be great if the [help center page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions) be more clear about this.

Comment: The help center page gives a rough outline about the most important deletion rules. For the full story, one has to find the FAQ link at the end and follow it. I guess that is as clear as it gets, repeating the full content of the FAQ page inside the help center page would IMHO not bring more clarity.